# Pandas - перемножение столбцов - not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, строки, pandas, float

есть Pandas df, в нем 2 колонки - почищенные и переведенные во float значения (astype):
Name: Бонус агенту, Length: 126268, dtype: float64
Name: Цена, руб., Length: 126268, dtype: float64
Мне необходимо где значения 'Бонус агенту' - меньше 1 (проценты) - перемножить с соответствующим значением из столбца 'Цена, руб' - остальное оставить как есть:
 `df['Бонус агенту']= np.where(df['Бонус агенту']<1,df['Бонус агенту']*df['Цена, руб.']/100, df['Бонус агенту'])`
error  '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.
Пробовал через маску и iloc - тоже отказывается сравнивать.
Буду признателен за ответ.

Comment: Суд по ошибке, тип данных в столбце 'Бонус агенту' - object (строковой). Что выводит: print(df.dtypes) ?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0):

Была заготовка - быстренько переделал под ваши условия в качестве примера и с выводом в файл формата csv.

```
# v.1.0, Assur 2-08-2020
import pandas as pd
import pytils
import csv

def csv_dict_writer(path, fieldnames, data):
    with open(path,"w") as out_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, lineterminator='\r\n',   delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
        out_file.close()

def write_rtext():
    my_list = []
    data = []
    path = "bonus.csv"
    fieldnames = ["proc_bonus_agent", "cena","oplata"]
    for row in range(0,len(rt1)):
        data.append({"proc_bonus_agent":rt1[row],"cena":rt2[row],"oplata":rt3[row]})
    csv_dict_writer(path, fieldnames, data)

file = 'bonus.xls'

xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df = []
nl = []
klv = [10]
rt1 = []
rt2 = []
rt3 = []

for i in range(1,2):
    df.append(xl.parse('Лист'+str(i)))
    nl.append(df[i-1].values.tolist())

    for j in range(0,klv[i-1]):
        val1 = float(nl[i-1][j][0])
        val2= float(nl[i-1][j][1])
        if val1 < 1:
            val3 = val1 * val2
        else:
            val3 = 0.0
        rt1.append(val1)
        rt2.append(val2)
        rt3.append(val3)

write_rtext()
```

Входные данные теста(Файл из LibreOffice, Linux. Обработка list pandas xsl  считывает данные со второй строки).

[image: входные данные]

Выходные данные в файле формата csv, открытые в текстовом редакторе выглядят так:

[image: выходные данные]

Comment: На картинке не попал шильдик с "Лист1" - он по умолчанию при создании нового xls в LibreOffice.

Comment: P.S. Код несколько избыточный. Есть варианты попроще.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Пытаюсь разобратся просто как преобразовать столбец Бонус агенту - в Pandas